# VBA Code to link checkboxes to certain columns

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I have three columns E(insufficient QTY) F(Too Slow) and G(Not Listed) They all have checkboxes in them. I need to link
E to H
F to I
G to J

The following code works nicely if there was only 1 column of checkboxes but I don't know how to improve the code to run by checkboxes in a certain column. Right now it just searches the entire sheet for checkboxes and links them to the desired column.

```
Sub LinkChecks()
'Update 20150310
i = 2
For Each cb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
cb.LinkedCell = Cells(i, "I").Address
i = i + 1
Next cb
End Sub
```

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be to name your checkboxes so that you can use their name in order to deduce which Column they are for. I.e., name it `Col1Checkbox1` so you can use `Instr(0,cb.Name,"Col1")` as part of a `if` statement

Comment: so if it is like 500 checkboxes I would have to name all 500?

Comment: Why not create the checkboxes programmatically? Then you can specify the column without the name.

Comment: Not 100% sure on how to do that. i was using kutools to batch make all the checkboxes.

Comment: `Set cb = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(99.75, 78, 24, 17.25)` then `cb.Name="yourname"` sets the name.  You can put this in a loop and change the x,y coordinates to generate the checkboxes

Comment: if its not to big of a deal could you write exactly how I would need to put that into vba. I am very new to vba.

Comment: You can also use Offset: 
`cb.LinkedCell = cb.Offset(i, 3).Address`
Since you know each column is three columns over from the current Checkbox.

Comment: for cb.LinkedCell = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Offset(i, 3).Address i got error run-time error '438': Object dosen't support this property or method.

Comment: Wow... you were quick.  As I hit enter, I realized I had a mistake.  I edited it, but you found my first entry.  Refresh your page and try `cb` instead of `activesheet.CheckBoxes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

Ok... let's try again:

Since the Check Box object does not have cell information for the cell it's located in, we will have to use the `Offset` property more creatively.

Since we know there are 3 check boxes per row, we can find the total number of check boxes and divide by 3 to find out how many rows there are.

Then by setting a Range to a single cell at the top of column "E", you can use the offset property on that cell.

Assuming you placed your Check Boxes on the sheet down column "E" sequentially, and then down column "F" next, then down "G", we can reset the offsets once we get to the last row of each column.  (If you place the check boxes on the sheet in row order, you'll have to invert the loop logic.)  (If you placed the check boxes on randomly, you are out of luck and will have to set your linked cells manually.)

```
Sub LinkChecks()

Dim rng As Range

Dim strColumn As String

Dim i As Integer
Dim intCount As Integer
Dim intRowCnt As Integer
Dim intRowOffset As Integer
Dim intColumnOffset As Integer
Dim dCnt As Double

i = 1               ' Your initial row offset
intCount = 0        ' A counter for total number of check boxes
intRowCnt = 0       ' A Row counter to find last row
intRowOffset = i    ' Current Row offset from initial rng cell
intColumnOffset = 3 ' Current Column Offset (3 over from first check box column)

strColumn = "E"     ' Set a starting Column of your first check box
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, strColumn) ' Set initial rng cell

' Count how many check boxes are on the active sheet
For Each cb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
   intCount = intCount + 1
Next cb

' Since you know you have 3 check boxes per row,
'   you can divide by 3 to get your row count
dCnt = intCount / 3
' *** Put test for remainder problems here ***

For Each cb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes

   cb.LinkedCell = rng.Offset(intRowOffset, intColumnOffset).Address
   intRowOffset = intRowOffset + 1

   ' Increment your row count until you get to last row
   intRowCnt = intRowCnt + 1
   If intRowCnt >= dCnt Then
      intRowCnt = 0 ' Reset you row counter
      intColumnOffset = intColumnOffset + 1 ' Increment Offset to the next column
      intRowOffset = i ' Reset Row offset back to top row
   End If

Next cb

End Sub
```

As long as your check boxes were placed on the sheet down each column, the above program should find the correct Linked Cell for each box.

If they were placed in a different order, then at least this code shows you how to set an initial Range cell and how you can reference other cells with an offset.

Hopefully this code or a combination of these ideas will help you with your problem. :)

Comment: it didn't like          cb.LinkedCell = cb.Offset(i, 3).Address

Comment: I made a change to the code to use a Range cell so the offset will work.  See if that helps.